# What's the proper way to bind text to properties of a Data Grid in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF Data Grid bound to an observable collection, which is working as intended.

What I am trying to do now is add text below it to say: "Number of selected rows: **{count goes here}**"

What's the proper way to do this?  I could add a new property in the View Model called `SelectedCount` or something similar and bind to that, but it doesn't feel right.  It seems redundant.  Also, I could set the label text dynamically in the code behind, but I'm not sure if that's the "right" place to do this either.

Here's an example below.

EDIT:

Please pretend there's a checkbox column header whose intention is to provide check/uncheck all functionality.  The state of this header checkbox should not count towards the final count.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use element binding to declaratively bind to the `SelectedItems.Count` property in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid,
   Path=SelectedItems.Count, StringFormat=Number of selected rows: {0}}" />
```

**Update**

Presumably you're using MVVM, so adding a `SelectedXCount` property to your view model is a perfectly reasonable application of the view model. The advantage of having it in the view model is that you could unit test based on the number of selected items. E.g. if you want to check that the user can only progress (a `CanNext` property returns true) if the user has selected some items.

The `SelectedItems` property is not a `DependencyProperty` so can't be bound to, but there are many articles online that get around the issue when using the DataGrid in MVVM. Most of the solutions involve using a mechanism for calling a view model command on the invocation of the DataGrid's `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: Yikes.  I should've also had this in the question.  There's a checkbox header too (for select all/unselected all).  counting that as a selected item would break this